# Adding to main.js causes - Uncaught TypeError: this.elements is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working through a Udemy course and have gotten to a module on writing our own version of jQuery. During this module, I created a js file, squery.js. The purpose of this file is to remove the need to use the period symbol to identify classes in the main.js file. I have written both files verbatim to what the instructor was using, but for some reason, I have several errors pop up.

In squery.js I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Parsing error: The keyword 'class' is reserved
```

In my main.js file, I get this error:

```
ERROR: 'sQuery' is not defined.[no-undef]
```

In the Chrome console, I get the following errors:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: this.elements is not a function TypeError: this.elements is not a function
    at squery.addClass (file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/Projects/Web-Course/js/squery.js:9:12)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/jason/Desktop/Projects/Web-Course/js/main.js:31:25)
    at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2:30307) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
t @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
B @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.elements is not a function
    at squery.addClass (squery.js:9)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:31)
    at e (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2)
addClass @ squery.js:9
(anonymous) @ main.js:31
e @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
t @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
S.readyException @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
e @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
t @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
t @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
B @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
```

I do not receive any console errors until I add the following code to main.js:

```
sQuery("my-selector").addClass("MYNEWCLASS");
```

My code:

squery.js

```
class squery {
  constructor(el) {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName(el);
  }

  addClass(cl) {
    var count = 0;
    while(count < this.elements.length){
      this.elements(count).className += " " + cl;
      count++;
    }
  }
}

function sQuery(el) {
  var element = new squery(el);
  return element;
}
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  sQuery("my-selector").addClass("MYNEWCLASS");
  // Remove Right Click Menu and Create our own context menu
  $(document).on('contextmenu', function () {
    return false;
  })
  $(document).on('mousedown', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(event.which == 3){

      $('.hidden').removeClass('shown');

      if ($(event.target).is('img')) {
        $('.saveimg, .newtab').addClass('shown');
      }else if ($(event.target).is('a')) {
        $('.newtab').addClass('shown');
      }

      console.log(event.pageY, event.pageX);

      $('#context').css({
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX
      });
      $('#context').fadeIn();
    }else if (event.which == 1) {
      $('#context').fadeOut();
    }

  })

  // Dropdown Menu
  $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var submenu = $(this).parent().find('.submenu');
    submenu.fadeIn(300);

    $('.profile-menu').on('mouseleave', function () {
      submenu.fadeOut(300);
    })

  });

  // Appending Prepending and Replacing
  $('#prepend, #append, #replace').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var action = el.attr('id');
    var content = $('.text').val();

    if(action == "prepend"){
      console.log("Prepending...");
      $('#main').prepend('<a href="#">' + content + '</a>');
    }else if (action == "append") {
      console.log("Appending...");
      $('#main').append(content);
    }else if (action == "replace") {
      console.log("Replacing...");
      $('#main').html(content);
    }

    $('.text').val('');
  });

});
```

Comment: `this.elements(count)` -> `this.elements[count]`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - This did it! Thank you for the extremely quick response!

Comment: I would like to mark this question as solved, but I am not seeing a checkmark or arrows near the comment.

Comment: You can mark the below answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax mistake in your code:

`this.elements(count)` would be `this.elements[count]`

`this.element(count)` would mean that it is a function and you are getting the error because it is an array.